# Finding Server name using IP address

Tags: ibm-midrange

A job is trying to connecting to a server. I could see the IP address to which the job is trying to connect. I would like to know if there is any command to find out the server name based on ip address in as400?

Comment: What about `ping -a`?

Comment: ping with the server name gives the IP of the server. I am trying the other way. I have server IP, trying to get server name.

Comment: I mean, does it work when you add `-a` to the `ping` command? On my PC: `ping 127.0.0.1` : Pinging 127.0.0.1 with ..., while `ping -a 127.0.0.1` : Pinging <ComputerName> [127.0.0.1] with ...

Comment: It is throwing error saying '- not in expression enclosed in parentheses.'

Comment: What command did you launch exactly?

Comment: ping -a 127.0.0.1 (I didn't mention the exact the IP what I have given in command)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186302/discussion-between-susmitha-and-dominique).

Comment: ping -a doesn't work on IBM i, the command parameters are different and this one (sadly) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

you can use nslookup command.
The NSLOOKUP command enables you to query name servers in order to accomplish the following tasks:

```
Locate information about network nodes
Examine the contents of a name-server database
Establish the accessibility of name servers
```

Comment: Is NSLOOKUP a CL command? I am trying to get the server name in as400.

Comment: @Susmitha [yes it is.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/nslookup.htm)

Comment: Did you attempt to prompt the command?

    NSLOOKUP HOSTNAME('192.168.1.1') DMNNAMSVR(*CFG)